# Найти в массиве слов string первое слово по алфавиту

Tags: c#

Кто подскажет может функция какая есть или как руками прописывать?Искать должно без учета регистра

Comment: А что логика подсказывает?

Comment: @MBo много чего, руки надеятся что есть готовая функция

Comment: функция `Min` .

Answer (score 1):

```
var words = new string[] { "cat", "apple", "battle" }; 
var firstWord = words.Min();

Console.WriteLine(firstWord);
```